# Django: Caching differs on Accept-Language request HTTP header

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, caching

I'm caching some APIs functions in a Django projects. My code basically looks like this:

```
@cache_control(max_age=1200)
@cache_page(60 * 60 * 24)
def data_as_json(request, argument_1, argument_2):
    #code
    return JsonResponse(rst)
```

and in settings.py:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'cache_table',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 1000
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed when I look in the cache table that the visitor's Accept-Language request HTTP header seems to be part of the cache key. Here is an example:
`:1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page..GET.3181615aba0959bd5afd815d19aedc92.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.en.Europe/Berlin`

I'm assuming this means that this cache object will only be used for users with the same Accept-Language request HTTP header? My website has few visitors and serve the same content to all visitors so I do not want the caching to depend on the visitor's location and language. Is there a way to change this?

I'm using Django 1.11 and Python 3.6.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sounds reasonable that if you have `USE_I18N = True` in your settings.py file, which is the Django default, caching would be language-dependent. If you're definitely not serving a multi-lingual website, set `USE_I18N` to False and I'd assume Django will ignore the Accept-Language from then on.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make difference. It still stores the language in the key. But still good tip to turn it off.

Comment: Surprising. But good to know. Maybe also try switching `USE_L10N` to False if you haven't tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's current behaviour is:

- `USE_I18N == True` or `USE_L10N == True`: The User Locale is appended to the cache key.
  Note: This is not the raw `Accept-Language` header value, it's the locale which Django derives from it!
- In all other cases (`USE_I18N` and `USE_L10N` are falsy) the raw User `Accept-Language` header value is appended to the cache key.

That means that it's currently not possible to cache content globally for all Locales.

For your use case it's probably the most viable option to enable `I18N` or `L10N` as it would reduce your cache key count slightly by only generating one cache key per locale and not per `Accept-Language` header value (which may vary per language!).

Check out [this relevant ticket #18191](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18191) and [the code changes](https://github.com/django/django/commit/6a057e1595dfe45a0411c116f603801266c87395#diff-118f78689b77ab87f5c98e73114cb7fe) which have remained mostly unchanged since Django 1.6.